# Creating a copy of primary database and attaching the copy database in the same sql instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just got into a project in which we have only one SQL Server 2012 copy. We have 12 databases attached to the primary instance of SQL Server 2012.

As I don't have SQL Server 2012 or supporting OS, I have to depend on the primary instance of SQL Server 2012.

I am not sure whether it is good to create copy/clone of all 12 databases and attach it to same instance and work on the copy for data manipulation and query testing purpose.

**Based on Kin's query**

```
SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.],
 SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation') AS Collation
```

Following is the output. I ignored PhysicalMachineName and SQLServerName.

```
ServerEdition : Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit)
ProductVersion : SQL Server 2012 + RTM + (Build11.0.2100.60)
O.S.           : Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) 
Collation      : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF the server is NOT a PRODUCTION server, then you can **backup** the databases you need for Data manipulation and **restore** them with databaseName_test.

Keep in mind that you will still be competing for resources on the server by creating another set of databases.

Why cant you install another instance of sql server ? Even the enterprise edition is free for 30 days (for evaluation purpose ONLY) or just buy a Developer edition which is much cheaper. If you have MSDN subscription, you will be able to get one. Windows Azure is also another option.

Below will give you the correct version and some more info :

```
     SELECT
   SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') AS PhysicalMachineName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('ServerName') AS SQLServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition') AS ServerEdition,
   CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version,charindex('SQL',@@version, 1),15) AS VARCHAR(255)) +  ' + ' 
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')AS VARCHAR (50)) + ' + (Build'
       + CAST (SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR (50)) +')' AS ProductVersion,
    RIGHT(@@version, (Len(@@Version)-charindex('Windows',@@version, 1))+1) AS [O.S.],
 SERVERPROPERTY ('Collation') AS Collation
```

Comment: If the databases are under 4gb you should also be able to use the express edition

Comment: Server is a Production Server. Just now i noticed, we have express edition. All database are less than 5 GB

Comment: backup restore is the way to go. I have **rarely** seen Production server running sql express.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Business Intelligence Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: i got the result from select version sql command

Comment: You should better know what you are working on.. as you said it is express edition and now it has changed !

Comment: Kin, Thank you. I have posted the query result in the Posting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12420/discussion-between-goofyui-and-kin)

Answer (score 1):

If your 12 databases are quite small - less then 10Gb I think is the current limit - you could use the free MSSQL 2012 server database and copy the databases into your own desktop. If they are larger then 10 Gb then it is possible to copy the structures over to the free instance and then populate with test data as required.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: Yes true. But i am using Windows XP. 2012 will not run on my Desktop

Comment: There are 2008 versions around, I think that the limit is lower but might still work. I ran 2008 on my XP, though I haven't tried 2012. I think this might help. http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=22973

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your copy of SQL Server is properly licensed for the physical machine, you can run multiple instances of SQL Server.  You can crreate a "test" instance, do a full backup of you production databases and then restore them to the new instance.  If you're worried about resource contention, you can configure settings ont the new instance like max memory and maxdop.

Comment: This is a Production Server. I am not sure,whether i am allowed to create another instance

Comment: i think we will not be able to install the same version of sql copy in a system. Might have to go for SQLExpress or another version!!